# SSRS conditional formatting based off a sum

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to do some conditional formatting in SSRS to set the cell to red if the sum is greater than 0, this is based off another sum which is already happening in the report.

This is what I have so far but it errors.

`=IFF(SUM(IIF(LEN(TRIM(Fields!TransferStock.Value))=0, 1, 0),"RED","White"))`

Thanks

Comment: What column type is `Fields!TransferStock.Value` and what is the error message?

Comment: Also, `IFF` should be `IIF`, but the answer below is a bit easier to apply to different scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work for the result of whatever is in the textbox.

`=IIF(Me.Value < 0, "Red", "Black")`

[image]

It's referenced in the following [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: No worries mate